# decodeSampledBitmapFromResource what to throw in parameters

Tags: image

Im trying to get my bitmap to fit in my imageview by using the tutorial on android devs but i dont know what to throw in this line `imageView.setImageBitmap(
                        decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, 100, 100));`

this is my full onActivityResult

```
 if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_CONTENT_RESOLVER) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image saved to a generated MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            String[] projection = {
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID,
                    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
            };
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(mPhotoUri, projection, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            String photoFileName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFileName);



            imageView.setImageBitmap(
                    decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, 100, 100));

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }


    }
```

these are the methods on the android devs

```
 public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

}

Im sorry if this is a not a good question but im trying to learn android developing at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

fix it by making the two methods into a class.